# draw a layer with some color in iPhone Application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, drawing

I would like to know how to draw a layer with some color [CGColorRef] in a window

When i am trying to addSubLayer to my window , the application is exiting without showing any exception.

Comment: I don’t think anyone here is going to write a whole app for you. But you need to look at the class `CALayer` and it’s property `backgroundColor`, I think.

Comment: No plz? You got some nerve trying to pull this off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app is just quitting with no debug error, there still could be a message sent to some deallocated instance.  Try turning on NSZombieEnabled by following the instructions here:
http://www.codza.com/how-to-debug-exc_bad_access-on-iphone

This will tell you when a bad message is sent.

Further, if you'd like to ask a question involving specific code, you'll get better responses.  Try posting your code and maybe we can help you with basic debugging.